# Output pretty table to an html file?

Tags: python, html, prettytable

I can't seem to get a clear cut answer on how to do this.  I have a pretty table that I print to the terminal but what if I want to create an html file and print the table to that html file?  How can this be done.

This is my table that I have, how could I go about writing this to a new html file?

```py
tbl = PrettyTable(["Occurs", "Occurrences"])
for word, cnt in matches.items():
    tbl.add_row([word, cnt])
tbl.align = 'l'
print(tbl.get_string(sortby="Occurrences", reversesort=True))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `get_html_string` ([doc on the github readme](https://github.com/jazzband/prettytable#displaying-your-table-in-html-form)) which will allow you to have the html and then you write the string into a html file like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path
tbl = PrettyTable(["Occurs", "Occurrences"])
for word, cnt in matches.items():
    tbl.add_row([word, cnt])
tbl.align = 'l'
to_save = tbl.get_html_string(sortby="Occurrences", reversesort=True)
with Path("my_html_file.html").open(mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    fp.write(to_save)
```